# Committing file if only modified using svnkit

Tags: java, svn, svnkit

I am using [svnkit](http://svnkit.com) in java for doing anykind of svn related stuff programatically.
I want to commit file only when it is changed. I am using this code snippet:

```
SVNDeltaGenerator deltaGenerator = new SVNDeltaGenerator();

        String checksum = deltaGenerator.sendDelta(filePath, new ByteArrayInputStream(oldData), 0, new ByteArrayInputStream(newData), editor, true);
```

This code is creating new version of the file whenever anyone tries to commit anything. I want to avoid this when the content of the remote file and local file is same.
Is there any way using svnkit library?
Thanks,

Amandeep

Comment: You could compare `oldData` and `newData` to check whether or not they match before allowing the commit. You could do something along the lines of hashing both and checking whether the resulting hash strings match etc... I have no knowledge on the svnkit library however, so I don't know whether it has this functionality available internally.

Comment: Thanks @CeilingGecko I am new to svnkit as well.I thought of similar solution but since old data and newData are byteArray not sure how I can compare them with complete correctness

Comment: You could use the `MessageDigest` class. [DOCS HERE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html) You can check an example: [HERE](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-md5-hashing-example/) To make it less error prone (because collisions) you can for example switch out the "MD5" to "SHA-256". And to check whether the `oldData` matches `newData` you can then just compare the hashed Strings to see if they match or not.

Comment: Thanks @CeilingGecko will definetely try this one out.